# Fetch only one row per condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table

```
+-------+-------+--------+
    id  |  myid | userid
+-------+-------+--------+
    1   |  123  |  321
    2   |  321  |  123
    3   |  123  |  444
    4   |  444  |  123
    5   |  123  |  555
+-------+-------+--------+
```

Now I want to fetch all rows where I have `myid='123'`

But as you see I have everywhere, I want to fetch all rows limited by 1
So in the end I get

`ids=[1,3,5]`

I use this to get all rows:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (myid='123' AND userid!='123') 
OR (userid='123' AND myid!='123') 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

But this will fetch all ids
Can I say this?

```
(
(myid='123' AND userid!='123') 
OR 
(userid='123' AND myid!='123') 
LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: What exactly you want? There is one '123' on every row, so why you don't want every row returned?

Comment: If I have messages and I want to get only one last row per conversation between 2 users

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE (myid = '123' and userid <> '123') OR (myid <> '123' and userid = '123')
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: read question pff, I don't want just one row I want one row per:
(myid='123' AND userid!='123') OR (myid!='123' AND userid='123')

Comment: OK. I made an edit that I believe should get you just that. Hope it helps.

Comment: *"read question pff"* - no need for attitude. People are here to "try" and help, given it's also "free" help. So please don't "look the gift horse in the mouth" as the saying goes. @Skyey

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
SELECT
    tbl1.id as id,
    t2.my_id as my_id,
    t2.userid as userid
FROM
    (SELECT
        max(t1.id) as id,
    FROM
        table t1
    WHERE
        t1.my_id = 123 or
        t1.userid = 123
    GROUP BY
        if(t1.my_id=123, t1.my_id, t1.userid),
        if(t1.my_id=123, t1.userid, t1.my_id)) tbl1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    table t2 on t2.id = tbl1.id
```

This should get you `ids=[2,4,5]`

Comment: If I have messages and I want to get only one last row per conversation between 2 users. If you understand I don't need last row I need last rows for conversation between 123 and 444, 123 and 321, 123 and 555

Comment: @Skyey So last row of each unique myid-userid pair?

Comment: @Skyey Please see the update

Comment: I think wait me to try it up

Comment: @Skyey I made another update, I think this should work now

Comment: @Skyey I updated again.

Comment: This didn't work but I totally forgot about DISTINCT that was what I needed

Comment: @Skyey Not sure which update you tried but I made another edit

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the [group_contact](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function of mysql

```
select group_concat(id SEPARATOR ',') from table where myid = '123'
union
select group_concat(id SEPARATOR ',') from table where userid = '123';
```

this only return 2 rows

Answer (score 0):

You could normalise the myid and userid columns like this

```
select  *,
            case 
                when myid < userid then myid 
                else userid 
            end as u1,
            case 
             when myid > userid then myid 
                else userid
            end as u2
from t
```

to give

```
+------+------+--------+------+------+
| id   | myid | userid | u1   | u2   |
+------+------+--------+------+------+
|    1 |  123 |    321 |  123 |  321 |
|    2 |  321 |    123 |  123 |  321 |
|    3 |  123 |    444 |  123 |  444 |
|    4 |  444 |    123 |  123 |  444 |
|    5 |  123 |    555 |  123 |  555 |
+------+------+--------+------+------+
```

then work out the max id like this

```
select max(id) from
(
select  *,
            case 
                when myid < userid then myid 
                else userid 
            end as u1,
            case 
             when myid > userid then myid 
                else userid
            end as u2
from t
) s
group   by u1,u2
```

to give this

```
+---------+
| max(id) |
+---------+
|       2 |
|       4 |
|       5 |
+---------+
```

and then join t like this

```
select   t.*
from        t
where  id in
(
select max(id) from
(
select  *,
            case 
                when myid < userid then myid 
                else userid 
            end as u1,
            case 
             when myid > userid then myid 
                else userid
            end as u2
from t
) s
group by u1,u2
)
```

to give this

```
+------+------+--------+
| id   | myid | userid |
+------+------+--------+
|    2 |  321 |    123 |
|    4 |  444 |    123 |
|    5 |  123 |    555 |
+------+------+--------+
```

No need to hardcode anything!! and if you prefer the first conversation change the max to min.